# не выводит нужный код

Tags: java

```
class zadach {
  public static void main(String[] args) {

    int month = 9;
    if ((month==1) || (month == 2) || (month == 12));
    {
       String zima = "Зима";
        System.out.println("Время года с номером месяца " + month + " - " + zima);
    }
    if ((month>=3) && (month<=5));
    {
        String vesna = "Весна";
        System.out.println("Время года с номером месяца " + month + " - " + vesna);
    }
    if ((month>=6) && (month<=8));
    {
        String leto = "Лето";
        System.out.println("Время года с номером месяца " + month + " - " + leto);
    }
    if ((month>=9) && (month<=11));
    {
        String osen = "Осень";
        System.out.println("Время года с номером месяца " + month + " - " + osen);
    }

  }
}
```

Выводит

```
Время года с номером месяца 9 - Зима
Время года с номером месяца 9 - Весна
Время года с номером месяца 9 - Лето
Время года с номером месяца 9 - Осень,
```

но нужно одну строку

Comment: а как мне сделать, чтобы вывелась одна строка с номером месяца и названием  времени года?

Comment: Вам дали верный ответ. Поставьте галку под ответом, чтобы принять его.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`;` уберите с конца строк с `if`.